# Iterating over the lines of a stream

Tags: c++, strings, io, iterator

This structure is supposed to iterate over the lines of an input stream, using `std::getline`. Any remark is welcome!

```
#include <iostream> //istream
#include <cassert>

struct line_iterator
{
    explicit
    line_iterator( std::istream & is )
        : m_stream( &is )
        , m_line( extract_line() )
    {
    }

    line_iterator()
        : m_stream( nullptr )
        , m_line()
    {
    }

    line_iterator( line_iterator & ) = default;

    std::string operator*()
    {
        assert( m_stream );
        return m_line;
    }

    line_iterator operator++()
    {
        assert( m_stream );
        update_stream();
        return *this;
    }

    line_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        line_iterator copy( *this );
        ++(*this);
        return copy; 
    }
private:
    void update_stream()
    {
        if ( m_stream->good() )
            m_line = extract_line();

        else
        {
            m_line.clear();
            m_stream = nullptr;
        }
    }

    std::string extract_line()
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline( *m_stream, line );
        return line;
    }

private:
    std::istream *  m_stream;
    std::string     m_line;

    friend bool operator!=( const line_iterator&, const line_iterator& );
    friend bool operator==( const line_iterator&, const line_iterator& );
};

inline
bool operator!=( const line_iterator & a, const line_iterator & b )
{
    return !(a.m_stream == b.m_stream);
}

inline
bool operator==( const line_iterator & a, const line_iterator & b )
{
    return a.m_stream == b.m_stream;
}
```

Comment: The standard already has a built-in technique for iterating over stream. `std::istream_iterator<Type>`. So you can iterate through a stream by object of `Type`. If you need to iterate by line then just define what that means in a type called `Line`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You might consider providing `typedef`s for the types expected by [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).
2. Your type should meet the requirements of [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator).  This means that you should also provide an overload for operator `->`.
3. The semantics of operator `!=` are not really useful.  For example, this won't allow you to use your iterator in the idiomatic

   ```
   line_iterator begin = …;
   line_iterator end = …;
   while (begin != end)
     {
       std::cout << *begin << std::endl;
       ++begin;
     }
   ```

   because there is no value you can set `end` to such that it compares not non-equal to `begin` only after `begin` was advanced a certain number of times.  I suggest you implement it somehow like this:

   ```
   friend bool
   operator!=(const line_iterator& lhs, const line_iterator& rhs) noexcept
   {
     if (lhs.m_stream == nullptr && rhs.m_stream == nullptr)
       return false;
     else if (lhs.m_stream == nullptr)
       return rhs.m_stream->good();
     else if (rhs.m_stream == nullptr)
       return lhs.m_stream->good();
     else
       return lhs.m_stream != rhs.m_stream;
   }
   ```

   This will allow you to use a default-constructed `line_iterator` as `end` and have it compare not non-equal to `begin` only after `begin`'s stream is exhausted.

   You should then implement `lhs == rhs` as `!(lhs != rhs)`.
4. You are making many copies of the string which is not as efficient as it could be.  I also feel that it makes your code more complicated than necessary.  You should read directly into `m_string` by implementing the increment operator as

   ```
   line_iterator&
   operator++()
   {
     assert(m_stream && m_stream->good());
     std::getline(*m_stream, m_string);
     return *this;
   }
   ```

   and the dereferencing operator as

   ```
   const std::string&
   operator*() const
   {
     return m_string;
   }
   ```

   In your constructor, default-construct `m_string` and (if the pre-conditions are met) advance once.
5. Personally, I prefer to only mention those members in the constructor's initializer list that depend on the constructor arguments.  Those that get default values I prefer to initialize in the class definition.

   ```
   class line_iterator
   {

   public:

     line_iterator()
     {
       // nothing to do
     }

     line_iterator(std::istream& istr) : m_stream {&istr}
     {
       if (m_istr->good())
         std::getline(*m_stream, m_string);
     }

     …

   private:

     std::string m_string {};     // defaults to empty string
     std::istream * m_stream {};  // defaults to 'nullptr'
   };
   ```
6. If you're going to make the `friend`s `inline` anyway, I'd prefer to define them right in the class body.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way of doing this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Line
{
     std::string   lineData;
     // Optional Way to convert a Line into std::string
     // operator std::string&() {return lineData;}
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Line& data)
     {
         return std::getline(stream, data.lineData);
     }
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Line const& data)
     {
         return stream << data.lineData << "\n";
     }
};

int main()
{
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Line>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<Line>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<Line>(std::cout, "Line: -> ")
             );
}
```